# Ruby code optimization: select from array

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm

Let's suppose that we class SomeClass.

```
class SomeClass < SomeClassThatAssignAttributesOnInitialization
  attr_accessor :group
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

And array of it instances

```
arr = [SomeClass.new(group:0, name:'one'),
       SomeClass.new(group:0, name:'two'),
       SomeClass.new(group:1, name:'three'),
       SomeClass.new(group:1, name:'four')]
```

I need to put first element of each group into array.

Now it works next way

```
current_group = nil
first_elements = arr.map do |instance|
  if current_group != instance.group
    current_group = instance.group
    instance.name
  end
end
```

This works fine but i think that there is some kind of "Ruby" way to do it.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: "some kind of 'Ruby' way" questions should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby has a handy `group_by` method on `Enumerable` object, which returns a `Hash`:

```
arr.group_by(&:group)
# => {0=>[#<SomeClass group=0, name="one">, #<SomeClass group=0, name="two">], 1=>[#<SomeClass group=1, name="three">, #<SomeClass group=1, name="four">]}
```

So just chain a few methods on to the end of that:

```
arr.group_by(&:group).values.map {|vs| vs[0].name}
# => ["one", "three"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.group_by(&:group).values.map(&:first)
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just:

```
first_elements = arr.map(&:name)
```

Comment: I need to take name from first element of each group. You example will take names from all elements

Comment: yeah sorry for that - I have noticed this after writing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeClass = Struct.new(:group, :name)

arr = [
  SomeClass.new(0, 'one'),
  SomeClass.new(0, 'two'),
  SomeClass.new(1, 'three'),
  SomeClass.new(1, 'four')
]

arr.group_by(&:group).values.map(&:first)
# => [
#   #<struct SomeClass group=0, name="one">,
#   #<struct SomeClass group=1, name="three">
# ]
```

Or to get just the names:

```
arr.group_by(&:group).values.map(&:first).map(&:name)
```